# Basic notation "$;$" question of math

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, notation

So I come across this "$;$" in almost every definition. Now I've seen that I actually don't really understand what it means.

Below is a definition of an optimization problem, which is defined by $\prod = (D,f,opt) $, this is the last subdefinition. 
Does the symbol "$;$" mean that the second part of the definition is the same as the first part but in other notation, or what exactly does it mean?

$$Opt(\prod) = \{x^* \in D(\prod); f(x^{*})=v^{*}(\prod) \}$$

If you need to know the background of this is: 
$v^{*}( \prod ) = opt\{ f(x), x \in D \} $ where this is an optimal solution to the problem 
and $D( \prod ) = D$ is a set of allowed solutions to the problem. This are the two subdefinitions and the third is the one written first, $Opt(\prod) = ...$

The question is also general for every math problem about this notation.

Comment: Most likely a shorthand for "such that" or "for" or "conditioned on". This might be written as : or ; or even with a comma as in $opt\{ f(x), x \in D \}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further context, I would interpret this as "set builder notation". Usually I would denote this with a bar $\mid$, but I have seen sets with $;$. That is, for the set of natural numbers greater than 5 we might write
$$
\{x \in \mathbb N \mid x > 5\},
$$
but we might also write
$$
\{ x \in \mathbb N ; x > 5\}.
$$
Similarly, in your case, I would interpret the set you describe as the set of those $x^*$ which are elements of $D(\Pi)$ such that the condition $f(x^*) = v(\Pi)$ holds.